# HQL case statement returning entity object

Tags: hibernate, hql, case

I have a table of records (I've ommited setters and other attributes for simplicity):

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="RECORD")  
public class Record {

    private long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID") 
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and a table of record collisions:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECORD_COLLISION")
public class RecordCollision {

    private long id;

    private Record firstRecord;

    private Record secondRecord;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "FIRST_RECORD")
    public Record getFirstRecord() {
        return firstRecord;
    }

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "SECOND_RECORD")
    public Record getSecondRecord() {
        return secondRecord;
    }
}
```

I need to select all records, which are colliding whith a specified record. I tried to use this HQL query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rc.firstRecord = :record THEN rc.secondRecord ELSE rc.firstRecord END 
    FROM RecordCollision rc 
    WHERE rc.firstRecord = :record OR rc.secondRecord = :record
```

I need to use the CASE statement because the specified record can be in column firstRecord, in which case I need to return secondRecord, and vice versa.

The problem is, that after executing query.list(), I dont get a list of instances of Record, but a list containing one instance of Object. It seems that Hibernate doesn't know it should return the result of the CASE statement as an instance of Record. How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Such a JPQL/HQL query can be written without select-case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(r) FROM Record r 
WHERE 
r.id in (SELECT rc1.firstRecord.id 
         FROM RecordCollision rc1 
         WHERE rc1.secondRecord = :record) 
OR 
r.id in (SELECT rc2.secondRecord.id 
         FROM RecordCollision rc2 
         WHERE rc2.firstRecord = :record)
```

If the one collision is presented by one row only, then `DISTINCT` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your alternative but isn't executing 2 subselects too inefficient for this?

Comment: Performance depends for example about query optimizer of database and amount of data. As it often is, without measuring it is impossible to say is it too inefficient.

Comment: Was it performing enough well or did you ended up with some other solution?

Comment: When writing this question, I already had a temporary solution using two separate queries and merging the results. This "temporary" solution eventually made it to production and is still used today (and most likely will not be changed anymore). Now I have a similar problem (which is why I came back to this question), and I'm going to use your solution. Although I think its not very effective, its still probably better than executing two separate queries.